# How do I unlock the Onion Knight job?

Tags: ios, psp, final-fantasy-3

In the original *Final Fantasy III*, Onion Knights were the default class. When the game was remade for the Nintendo DS, Freelancers became the default class and Onion Knights were unlocked via a secret quest involving the Mognet.

When this remake was ported to iOS devices, Mognet was removed. However, [the Wikipedia article for *Final Fantasy III*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_Fantasy_III) mentions this:

> A port of the remake for iOS was released on March 24, 2011. In which the game-play and graphics where improved sound was also remastered But the Mail/Mognet to other players was removed. And the "Onion Knight" was found in another quest.

What is that quest, and what are the steps one needs to take to unlock the Onion Knight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quote from another FF wiki:

> In the iOS version, the quest is opened up after defeating Gutsco in the Molten Cave and reading all of the letters Topapa sends you up until that point.

[Source](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Onion_Knight_%28Final_Fantasy_III%29#Obtaining_the_Job)

Comment: There's more to the quest than just reading all of the letters. Should the rest of the requirements be listed here?

Comment: @Yuck Yes, they should :)